# How to hide the controls and autoplay an iframe mp4 video

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, video, iframe

I have been trying to find an answer for this question for awhile and there must be a simple solution.

On my website I have a short video which I need to autoplay and loop while hiding the controls however nothing I have tried will work. The video plays correctly in other browsers but google chrome (I am aware of the recent change of policy with Chrome but I need the video to play in all browsers) will not work. I have tried using the video tag and putting the video on mute but this didn't work so I am now trying to display the video using an iFrame.

Here is my code below

```
<iframe class="video1" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/dashboard.mp4" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

The video is a 2 second gif like video and it is very important that it both autoplays and loops for the functionality of my website.

Comment: Have you tried adding `allow="autoplay"` to your `iframe`? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: _“it is very important that it both autoplays and loops”_ - both not achievable by just referring to the video file directly in an iframe. `video` element is the way to go.

Comment: @misorude is it not possible to use autoplay on a video tag in google chrome re their recent changes in policy.

Comment: Good :-) But it won’t loop by just pointing an iframe to the mp4 file directly either. If anything, you would need to load some sort of player inside the iframe, that plays and loops the video - but that has the same problem then again, just one level deeper. _“and there must be a simple solution“_ - no, there must not necessarily. Google explicitly prevents what you are trying to pull here, because it goes on people’s nerves too much.